# How to set profile picture app from Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-gallery

I want a simple way where there is an ImageView representing a user profile picture.  It is set to a default photo if they have not picked one.

I would like them to simply click on it and it opens up the gallery and they can set (and crop) a profile picture.  That picture than is set in the ImageView (and stays there the next time the app is opened -- I am also using an Internet MySQL database to connect to that I may need to store the picture in so other users can see.  I just need to see the Android side of things).

I am assuming I may need to use an Intent of some sort? Can I see basic code on how one might do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on using an intent with the Gallery: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/gallery-intent-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for this @toadzky .  It helped me :-)